# How can I convert text to column in R with rows having different column names in the row

Tags: r, arrays

Below is a subset of my data in which I have a column called "info" that has a lot of information in it.

```
name        info
call_2        BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=1;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DEL
call_3        BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=1;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DEL
call_4        BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=1;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DEL
call_5        BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=1;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DEL
call_6        BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=1;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DEL
call_7        BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=1;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DEL
call_9        BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=4;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DUP
call_10      BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=3;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DUP
call_11      BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=3;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DUP
call_12      BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;COPY=3;MATCHES=.;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV;TYPE=DUP
call_478    ALLELIC_FRAC=0.47263681592;BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;FRAC_HAP_SUPPORT=0.610526315789;HAPS=1,1;HAP_ALLELIC_FRAC=0.994285714286;LR=11.1274030188;MATCHES=.;NPAIRS=38;NSPLIT=0;ORIENT=-+;PS1=10934620;PS2=19549611;RP_LR=458;RP_TYPE=TRANS_FR;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=CNV,SV;TYPE=UNK;ZS=HET
call_479    ALLELIC_FRAC=0.017982017982;BLACK1=.;BLACK2=.;BLACK_DIST1=inf;BLACK_DIST2=inf;BLACK_FRAC=0.0;HAPS=.,.;HAP_ALLELIC_FRAC=1.0;LR=2.03176935202;MATCHES=.;NPAIRS=1;NSPLIT=0;ORIENT=..;PS1=112377837;PS2=112377837;RP_LR=12;RP_TYPE=TRANS_FF;SEG_DUP=.;SOURCE=SV;TYPE=DUP;ZS=HOM
```

There are up to 19 types of information contained in this column (listed below). Each piece of information is always separated by its corresponding value by an '=' sign and is separated by the next piece of information by a semicolon.

```
"BLACK1", "BLACK2", "BLACK_DIST1", "BLACK_DIST2", "BLACK_FRAC", "NPAIRS", "NSPLIT", "SEG_DUP", "ALLELIC_FRAC", "FRAC_HAP_SUPPORT", "HAP_ALLELIC_FRAC", "MATCHES", "TYPE", "ORIENT", "RP_LR", "RP_TYPE", "PS1/PS2", "HAPS", "ZS"
```

My goal is to add 19 columns to this dataset and add the corresponding value from the Info column to the respective new column. In this case, things like '.' and '.,.' are also considered data values. I am not sure how to go about doing this in R.

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr` is really helpful here:

```
library(tidyr)
d %>% 
  separate_rows(info, sep = ';') %>% 
  separate(info, c('argument', 'value'), sep = '=') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = argument, values_from = value)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 x 24
>    name  BLACK1 BLACK2 BLACK_DIST1 BLACK_DIST2 BLACK_FRAC COPY  MATCHES SEG_DUP SOURCE TYPE  ALLELIC_FRAC
>    <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>       
>  1 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        1     .       .       CNV    DEL   NA          
>  2 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        1     .       .       CNV    DEL   NA          
>  3 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        1     .       .       CNV    DEL   NA          
>  4 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        1     .       .       CNV    DEL   NA          
>  5 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        1     .       .       CNV    DEL   NA          
>  6 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        1     .       .       CNV    DEL   NA          
>  7 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        4     .       .       CNV    DUP   NA          
>  8 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        3     .       .       CNV    DUP   NA          
>  9 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        3     .       .       CNV    DUP   NA          
> 10 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        3     .       .       CNV    DUP   NA          
> 11 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        NA    .       .       CNV,SV UNK   0.472636815…
> 12 call… .      .      inf         inf         0.0        NA    .       .       SV     DUP   0.017982017…
> # … with 12 more variables: FRAC_HAP_SUPPORT <chr>, HAPS <chr>, HAP_ALLELIC_FRAC <chr>, LR <chr>, NPAIRS <chr>,
> #   NSPLIT <chr>, ORIENT <chr>, PS1 <chr>, PS2 <chr>, RP_LR <chr>, RP_TYPE <chr>, ZS <chr>
> ```